# Performance on updating row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, update, query-performance

When updating in SQL Sever, it is my understanding that the entire row is deleted and then recreated (which is why you get a new timestamp).  So then, if you update 1 field or 500 fields, does the performance of the update change?

I suspect that if there are indexed columns, as it has to update the index, there would be more "work" for the server to perform.  When answering, assume that there are no triggers.

Comment: "the entire row is deleted and then recreated" is not correct. SQL Server has a mechanism called update-in-place which can be used when the new data is the same size or smaller than the old data and the updated columns are not part of a clustered index.

Comment: Very interesting, I have to do some more research starting here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2011/06/21/are-all-updates-split-into-delete_2D00_insert_3F00_/

Comment: Oops, there should have been some links there. Sorry Dan. My authoritative source is the ["Inside"](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Inside-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005-Kalen-Delaney/9780735621053) series of books by Kalen Delaney and Itzik Ben Gan. Also Brent Ozar's [Stop Worrying about Fragmentation](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/).

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to decide whether to build a dynamic or CASE expression, omitting columns whose values haven't changed, I'd say that it depends on your index structure, and you will need to test. In this article, I found that with a single, simple, clustered primary key, the blind update was always faster; this changed *in some scenarios* when multiple indexes were added.

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/conditional-updates

Where the breaking point is, I'm not sure; nor did I test with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the article.  My excursion is to find out if `update x set name = 'x'` performs as well as `update x set name = 'x', age = 1, ... ... zip = '44111'` assuming that all of the other columns' (age ... ... zip) values do not really change.  My assertion is that if the columns change or not, the performance is the same.

Comment: @SomeFreeMason You'll have to test it. As my article demonstrates, *it depends*.

Comment: I'll post my results from the testing.